# Formatting SQL WHERE Conditional Values

Tags: plsql, formatting

I am looking to see if there is a way to format conditional values in batch instead of manually typing.  For example, I am filtering on 5 digit codes in SQL, my source of the codes is in Excel in list form.  There can be hundreds of codes to add to a SQL WHERE statement to filter on, is there tool or formatting methods the will take a list of values and format with single quotes and comma separation?

From this:

```
30239
30240
30241
30242
```

To this:

```
'30239',
'30240',
'30241',
'30242',
...
```

Then, these formatted values can be pasted into the WHERE clause instead of manually typing all of this out.  Again, this is for hundreds of values...

I used to use BrioQuery that had functionality to import text files to be used in filtering, but my current qry tool, TOAD Data Point does not seem to have this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Look into [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-commands.html#GUID-CD662CD8-DAA7-4A30-BC84-546E4C40DB31).  Create s staging table to contain the imported values. Use loader to populate the stage table. Then modify your query to reference the stage table; it becomes something like:

```
Select ... 
 where target_column_name in (select column_name from stage_table).
```

The structure "where in ( select)" may not be the best for performance, but once loaded you will have all the facilities SQL offers at your disposal.

It has been a few years since I've used TOAD but as I remember it has an import functionality. There are other tools for loading data into Excel into Oracle. SQL*Loader just happens to be the one Oracle supplies with the RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I do not have write access to the dbase.

Comment: Then talk with your DBA or have your manager do so. Get an area set up for this purpose for you and your team.  This is a business need. Keep in mind that you and the DBA are **members of the same team** (at least as for as the rest of the organization is concerned). Each of has a professional obligation to deliver the most optimum solution to your employee or client. You typing 100's of numbers is not it. What you have is an organizational problem - solve it.   OK, I'll get off my soapbox.